# Remote client and server communication using TCP sockets in c++

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, tcpclient, socketserver

I want to run server and clients using socket programming remotely (clients from my pc and server on a remote host). I have written a program in C++ that runs on local machine, both the client and the server. Now how can I run the server from a different machine? Here in server.cpp I have used INADDR_ANY, I don't have any idea how to give IP address of my PC(on which server is running) to the clients and the ip adddress of the pc (on which I have my client program) to the server. And does client and server have the same port number or they can have a different port number as well? If yes, then how can I assign that?

server.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

void main()
{

    WSADATA data;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    int wres = WSAStartup(ver, &data);
    if (wres != 0)
    {
        cerr << "unable to initialize winsock" << endl;
        return;
    }


    SOCKET listening = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (listening == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cerr << "unable to create a socket" << endl;
        return;
    }

    sockaddr_in sdata;
    sdata.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sdata.sin_port = htons(54000);
    sdata.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = INADDR_ANY;

    bind(listening, (sockaddr*)&sdata, sizeof(sdata));

    listen(listening, SOMAXCONN);


    sockaddr_in client;
    int csize = sizeof(client);

    SOCKET clientsock = accept(listening, (sockaddr*)&client, &csize);

    char host[NI_MAXHOST];
    char service[NI_MAXSERV];

    ZeroMemory(host, NI_MAXHOST);
    ZeroMemory(service, NI_MAXSERV);

    if (getnameinfo((sockaddr*)&client, sizeof(client), host, NI_MAXHOST, service, NI_MAXSERV, 0) == 0)
    {
        cout << host << " connected on port " << service << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &client.sin_addr, host, NI_MAXHOST);
        cout << host << " connected on port " <<
            ntohs(client.sin_port) << endl;
    }
    //listening
    closesocket(listening);
    

    char buf[4096];
    //char temp[] = "Hello";
    //char *input = temp;
    string input;
    int inputsize;
    while (true)
    {
        ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);


        int recbyte = recv(clientsock, buf, 4096, 0);
        if (recbyte == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            cerr << "Error in recv(). Quitting" << endl;
            break;
        }

        if (recbyte == 0)
        {
            cout << "Client disconnected " << endl;
            break;
        }
        cout << "Client>";
        cout << string(buf, 0, recbyte) << endl;
         
        cout << "> ";
        getline(cin, input);


        send(clientsock, input.c_str(), input.size() + 1, 0);

    }


    closesocket(clientsock);

    WSACleanup();

    system("pause");
}
```

client.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    string ipAddress = "127.0.0.1";         
    int port = 54000;                       

    WSAData data;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int wsResult = WSAStartup(ver, &data);
    if (wsResult != 0)
    {
        cerr << "Can't start Winsock, Err #" << wsResult << endl;
        return;
    }

    
    SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cerr << "Can't create socket, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ipAddress.c_str(), &hint.sin_addr);


    int connResult = connect(sock, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
    if (connResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cerr << "Can't connect to server, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(sock);
        WSACleanup();
        return;
    }

    
    char buf[4096];
    string userInput;

    do
    {
        
        cout << "> ";
        getline(cin, userInput);

        if (userInput.size() > 0)       
        {

            int sendResult = send(sock, userInput.c_str(), userInput.size() + 1, 0);
            if (sendResult != SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                
                ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);
                int bytesReceived = recv(sock, buf, 4096, 0);
                if (bytesReceived > 0)
                {
                    
                    cout << "SERVER> " << string(buf, 0, bytesReceived) << endl;
                }
            }
        }

    } while (userInput.size() > 0);

    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

Comment: The server does not need to know the client's IP address, it can use `IPADDR_ANY` to accept connections from any IP address. The client needs to know the server's IP address. How it goes about it, is entirely up to you. There is no law that says how a client figures out the server's IP address. Whichever way you go about it, anywhere from a hardcoded server address, to implementing complicated network discovery protocols, is entirely up to you to choose. And the server's port has nothing to do with the client's port. In fact, `connect()` chooses a random port ***by default***.

Comment: Can it be that you asked this or a similar question already today? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64523841/communication-b-w-server-and-clients-using-tcp-sockets-on-different-machines-c looks very similar.

Comment: ...after it was closed as duplicate. Don't you understand why duplicates are being closed? It's not so that you delete the question and ask it again!

Comment: Of course the client needs to know the server's port number. How else could it possibly connect to the server?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I want the server to accept the connections from a particular ip address. How can I do that? What should I use instead of INADDR_ANY in server.cpp?

Comment: No, you should still use `INADDR_ANY`. `accept()` tells you the IP address the connection is from, and if you don't find the client's IP address to your liking you immediately `close` the socket. Or, you will need to use your operating system's firewall to implement this restriction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you do not fully understand the client-server roles.
The server does not, cannot and should not know the address of the client connecting to it (although it can know it AFTER the connection).
To accomplish the connection, the clients need to know the IP and PORT to which they should connect, and the server should bind its server port (on which it listens) to the correct IP and PORT.
The default IP is usually depicted using the INADDR_ANY, and on most cases this is OK, but if you have more than one address on the machine you may have to specify another address.
The clients usually do not bind their connecting sockets as their own port numbers is not important. Also their own IP is not important as it is not used during the connection.
So what you should do is run your server application on your PC, and give your PC's address and the PORT number to all clients seeking to connect to you.